# how to pass a ListView by value and not by reference?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I have a function that uses my listView items, and in my function I need to remove Items from the list :

```
bool isTherePath(ListView^ allSysParamsList, ListView^ paramList,String^ source,String^ target)
```

my problem is that when items are being removed , they are removed also from my main form that called the function. 
how do I pass this ListView as a copy and not a reference , so that the original ListView remains intact ?

Comment: What do you need from the ListView? Can't you just pass a new List<> holding all ListView items instead?

Comment: This is not possible, you need to stop trying.  ListView, like all Control classes, is not serializable, it has entirely too much runtime state associated with it.  In native C++ speak, it is equivalent to std::thread, can't copy that either.  You need to solve this problem by separating the model from the view.  Party on a `List<Something>^` all you want, what the user looks at should be disconnected, a snapshot of the data.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks .. post as answer